# I need to format with a comma separator and two decimals

Tags: sql

In this problem, I needed to find the sum of these ticket prices, round it to two decimals and put a comma in the thousands' place. I know how to sum and format simultaneously, and sum and round simultaneously but not format and round.

this is the code I tried

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(seat_price) , 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Total Possible Revenue'
FROM seat;
```

and I am getting 490,100 as a result but I want 490,100.00

Comment: FORMAT(SUM(seat_price) ,'#,###.00')    note the zeros vs the zero surpressed #'

Comment: 1. MySQL <> SQL Server; only tag the product you are *really* using. 2. There are plenty of examples on how to round numerical data, what was wrong with those? 3. Formatting is for presentation layer, not the SQL layer; leave the value as a numerical data type and the add the commas when you *present* the data to the user.

Comment: although others helping on the FORMAT() function, I would ask this.  How is the final output, via some web process, desktop interface, an Excel (or other Google Docs or similar)?   If so, I would not worry about the formatting of the data, just get the raw numbers.  Let the output mechanism actually deal with the format.  You just provide the underlying data.  Similarly would apply for dates, date/time formatting as well... But just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Add a 2 to the format specifier ('N2'). This indicates to return the number with two decimal places:

```
> SELECT FORMAT(SUM(seat_price) , 'N2', 'en-us') AS 'Total Possible
> Revenue' FROM seat;
```